# FTP passive mode, fails

Tags: iptables, ftp

Hi I am trying to setup iptables to allow FTP. When I connect with FTP, i get the following message in my filezilla.

```
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to: Binary.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering passive mode (X,X,X,X,225,8).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 File status okay. About to open data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

My IP tables look like this: http://pastebin.com/er1CtZjZ

Any assistance I would be most greatful.

Comment: it does not help a lot to just dump your rule set without any documentation what you intend with all these rules. i suggest that you first try without any iptables, because often FTP has problems even if no iptables is involved. If it works without iptables try with only the rules you want to add for FTP. If this works you can add more rules and please document them.

Comment: In order to look for the problem the IP deny log is highly useful, try `dmesg | grep -wi firewall` - but maybe the answer below already helps.  (Also if you have ipfilters on your client or router (by default, there are no relevant ones) these might be a cause for trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the ftp deamon to run you need to open incoming TCP ports of some range, say 40000:41999 and match these against a matching configuration file of your ftp daemon.  I have, for instance, in my `/etc/proftpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost ftp.foo.bar>
  Port 21
  DefaultRoot ~
  HiddenStores on
  PathDenyFilter (\\.ftpaccess|\\.htaccess|\\.php|\\.rar)
  Umask 077
  DirFakeGroup on
  DirFakeUser on
  DefaultTransferMode binary
  DeferWelcome on
  MaxClients 12 "Too many logins"
  MaxClientsPerHost 4 "Too many logins"
  PassivePorts  40000 41999
</VirtualHost>
```

PS: Do I need to say it?  Of course incoming ports 20 and 21 must also be open for control connections.